# Remove span tags from WooCommerce Downloads page

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, filters, html

Hello i have problem with my woocommerce downloads section in "my account" page - span tags between product name and variation name.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIg0X.png

I tried to make a snippet:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_available_downloads', 'remove_span_dl_name', 10, 7);
function remove_span_dl_name( $download ){
return str_replace( '<span> - </span>', ' - ',$download['download_name']);
}
```

but it removes all downloads altogether.

And this one do nothing:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_download_link', 'remove_span_dl_name', 10, 7);
function remove_span_dl_name( $download ){
return str_replace( '<span> - </span>', ' - ',$download['download_name'] );
}
```

What is my mistake and how can I get rid of these tags?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `str_replace` looks for an **exact** match of the 'needle' (what you are searching for; 'haystack' is the thing you are searching inside). So your code is not finding an exact match.

If you want to do a 'replace everything that might be within the span codes in that hunk of text', then a regex statement might be in order. This is assuming that the 'haystack' you are searching is different each time. (Since I don't read your language, can't tell for sure.

But, assuming that `$download['donload_name']` contains the start and stop span tag, and something in the middle, then try to do two str_replace commands: one for the `<span>` and one for `</span>`.

And that assumes that there aren't any parameters to the `<span>`. If there are, a regex might be better idea.

Comment: Thanks for idea!